# Swift 2.2 on Mavericks 10.9.5 ?

Tags: swift, osx-mavericks

I don't like Yosemite&El Capitan because too slow. My question: Xcode 6.2 for Mavericks (Swift 1.2) but i want develop app with Swift 2+. Is it possible to write code on Mavericks with Swift 2+ ?

Sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's impossible. XCode 7 with swift 2.+ is available only for 10.10.5 (Yosemite) and above:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_5.0_.2B_.28with_arm64_support.29